# Kotlin throws NullPointerException, pointing not to code but to funcion name, when reading data with Datastore and Gson

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack

In my mobile app, written with Kotlin and Android Jetpack Compose, I am saving some user data from web service to DataStore. For user data I have UserModel data class, it's content is not important here, and DataStore is implemented as Repository.

DataStoreRepository.kt:

```
interface DataStoreRepository {

    fun saveUserCache(user: UserModel)
    fun readUserCache(): UserModel
}
```

DataStoreRepositoryImpl.kt:

```
const val DATASTORE_NAME = "settings"
const val USER_CACHE = "USER_CACHE"

private val Context.dataStore : DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = DATASTORE_NAME)

class DataStoreRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val context : Context,
    private val gson: Gson
): DataStoreRepository {

    override fun saveUserCache(user: UserModel) = runBlocking {

        val json = gson.toJson(user)
        saveString(USER_CACHE, json)
    }

    override fun readUserCache(): UserModel = runBlocking {

        val json = readString(USER_CACHE) ?: "" // Android Studio shows json variable as String -> OK

        // tried also this without success, using below code didn't help, but what was interesting for me json variable was shown as... String? -> why?
        //val json = try {
        //    readString(USER_CACHE)
        //} catch (_: Exception) {
        //    ""
        //}

        return@runBlocking try {
            gson.fromJson(json, UserModel::class.java)
        } catch (_: Exception) {
            UserModel()
        }
    }
    
    private suspend fun saveString(key: String, value: String) {

        val prefsKey = stringPreferencesKey(key)
        context.dataStore.edit {
            it[prefsKey] = value
        }
    }
    
    private suspend fun readString(key: String): String? {

        return try {

            val prefsKey = stringPreferencesKey(key)
            val prefs = context.dataStore.data.first()
            prefs[prefsKey]

        } catch (e: Exception) {

            Timber.e(e)
            return null
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my AppModule.kt (just in case):

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    // GSON

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideGson(): Gson {

        return GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate::class.java, LocalDateAdapter())
            .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime::class.java, LocalDateTimeAdapter())
            .create()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatstoreRepository(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context,
        gson: Gson
    ): DataStoreRepository {
        return DataStoreRepositoryImpl(context, gson)
    }
}
```

When I save data and then try to read it in some viewmodel, then it works perfect.

Problems start when I am trying to read data before something was saved there. I was given error which I do not understand (yes formatting of this curly braces is as in Android Studio Logcat):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: override fun readUserCac…erModel()
    }
} must not be null
at REMOVED_MY_PACKAGE_NAME.data.repository.DataStoreRepositoryImpl.readUserCache(DataStoreRepositoryImpl.kt:170)
at REMOVED_MY_PACKAGE_NAME.presentation.components.PwNavigationViewModel.<init>(PwNavigation.kt:132)
at REMOVED_MY_PACKAGE_NAME.DaggerPwApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get(DaggerPwApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:712)
at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory$1.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:102)
at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:90)
at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:114)
```

Line DataStoreImpl.kt:170 points exactly to this:

```
override fun readUserCache(): UserModel = runBlocking {
```

I have feeling that error occurs when doing gson.fromJson(json, UserModel::class.java), but I surrounded it with try-catch to return empty UserModel() in case of some problems (i.e. when there is no data under USER_CACHE key or when data is malformed.

What can cause such problem? How can I fix it? Every help is appreciated :)

Comment: Why would you combine modern kotlin solution (datastore) with ancient java reflection-based library (gson) in the first place?

Comment: Set `.setLenient()` for your Gson in `provideGson` function.

Comment: @Pawel, code is being rewritten, so for now it uses GSon as it used before, changing to Moshi is in plans.

Comment: @Mohammad In my case it doesn't work, as the JSON is empty string and there is no way that GSon will make something from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gson.fromJson` returns `null` from an empty String. But the Kotlin compiler does not know that, and treat it as the [platform type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types).

`runBlocking` does not care about the return type and pass the null up. But `readUserCache` expect a non-null value, so it throws.

---

Rewriting a bit to make the point clear.

```
fun readUserCache(): UserModel {
    // implicit null check here fails
    //              vvvvvvvvvvv
    val tempVariable: UserModel = runBlocking {
        // runBlocking does not mind that a null is returned here
        return@runBlocking gson.fromJson("", UserModel::class.java)
    }
    return tempVariable

}
```

---

An ugly solution is to throw early

```kotlin
gson.fromJson(json, UserModel::class.java)!!
```

Then in your code it will be caught, and a empty `UserModel()` returned.